# Cannot refresh Kendo Grid by a custom button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have tried many different methods suggested in stackoverflow and on the other pages but still cannot refresh data on the Kendo Grid. I encounter "TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined" error when applying the following methods. Any help pls?

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<button id="refresh" class="k-button" onclick="Refresh()">Refresh</button>


<script>
    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        //code omitted for brevity
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Event/Event_Read",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false
                    }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        CardNo: { type: 'number' }
                        //code omitted for brevity                         
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        pageable: {
            pageSize: 15,
            refresh: true
        },
        filterable: true,
        columns:
        [
            { field: "CardNo", title: "Card No", filterable: true }
            //code omitted for brevity              
        ]
    }).data("kendoGrid");

    function Refresh() {
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Try putting your grid initialization in a `$(document).ready()`

Comment: As a warning, do not spam links to this question across the site in comments. These comments are being flagged and removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi try this code instead, include the following css and js and try reloading grid.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="grid"></div>
<button id="refresh" class="k-button" onclick="Refresh()">Refresh</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    //code omitted for brevity
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/Event/Event_Read",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false
                }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    CardNo: { type: 'number' }
                    //code omitted for brevity                         
                }
            }
        }
    },
    pageable: {
        pageSize: 15,
        refresh: true
    },
    filterable: true,
    columns:
    [
        { field: "CardNo", title: "Card No", filterable: true }
        //code omitted for brevity              
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");

function Refresh() {
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
}
});
</script>
```

worked for me and for reference have a look at [this](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index) telerik website.

Comment: Thanks Milan. Yes, that is exactly jquery problem but not caused from missing jquery file. Adding jquer file two times by bundling and normal definition. Removing one of the definition solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should refresh the grid:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

The refresh method populates the grid again from the data source. If the data hasn't change the grid won't change either.

If you getting firebug error

> TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined

it means that the grid is not yet initialized when this code is invoked or that the selector is wrong.
Make sure that you dont mix up the name of grid with some other control

Try by changing Your selector name.

```
$("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

Comment: @Salam Abbas, there is no problem regarding to the names of selectors. I found that the problem is caused from jquery definitions as I explained above. Anyway, your answer is also very helpful for me :) Voted+

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
$(".k-pager-refresh").trigger('click');
```

in your refresh function

or try this

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read(); 
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
```

This helps you

Regards,